# Razor Pages routing breaks when creating web host from separate project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to create a service which will run two hosts: the main service, and a web interface to go along with it. They should run concurrently. As far as I can tell, the pattern I should use for this is to create 3 projects; a bootstrap project, a "main service" one, and a "web interface" one (which is an ASP.NET Razor Pages project). My bootstrap `Main` looks like:

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args) {
    var botHost = MyBot.Service.HostSetup
        .CreateHost(args, _serviceName, _serviceDescription)
        .RunAsync();
    var webHost = MyBot.Web.WebHostSetup
        .CreateWebHost(args)
        .RunAsync();

    await Task.WhenAll(new Task[] { botHost, webHost });

    Console.WriteLine("All hosts exited.  Exiting program.");
}
```

`CreateHost` and `CreateWebHost` return an `IHost`.

The regular service `IHost` runs fine, and it's created via `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args) [...] .Build()`. However, the Razor Pages web host fails to discover any Razor pages paths, giving the following logs when I try to access the root of the site:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:5001/ - -
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware[4]
      The request path / does not match a supported file type
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher[1000]
      No candidates found for the request path '/'
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware[2]
      Request did not match any endpoints
```

Apparently something about the Razor Pages project being separate from the project containing `Main` causes the `DfaMatcher` discovery (what does "Dfa" stand for, anyway?) to fail. `CreateWebHost` looks like:

```
public static IHost CreateWebHost(string[] args) {
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

    // Add services to the container.
    builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

    var app = builder.Build();

    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment()) {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.MapRazorPages();

    return app;
}
```

How can I fix the Razor Pages project and get it to correctly discover the Razor pages?